# Is wxHaskell dead?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

It seems to be dead. Is it?

If it is, what should I use instead?

Comment: Most the time I see people using [gtk](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) or even building directly on [GLUT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.2.2.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[gtk2hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs) is very much alive... I think it's too early to announce wxhaskell's demise, yet. Hackage says the May version builds fine with ghc7, there might be other reasons there hasn't been an update.

...unless, of course, you're looking for more haskelly approaches to GUI like [grapefruit](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Grapefruit), none of which are really ready for prime time, though, due to the general epicness of getting [FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) right.

Answer (score 2):

wxHaskell is actively maintained for several years now.

Comment: While this is not a really good answer, others should note that its author is one of the current maintainers of `wxHaskell`.